# React-native - How to create a scrollable flatList in which the chosen item is the one at the middle?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I would like to create a scrollable FlatList to select only one item among a list. After the user scroll the list, the selected item will be the one in the colored rectangle (which have a fixed position) as you can see here :

[image]

Actually I'm only able to render a basic FlatList even after some researches.

Do you know how I should do that ?

Comment: I think you can use initialScrollIndex prop in flatlist. Please read the documentation of flatlist.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to set the initial position of the list. I want the user to scroll the choice list and when he click next : the selected choice is considered at the one in the black rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (but it's not a FlatList) !

To do that I use :
https://github.com/veizz/react-native-picker-scrollview.

To define the background of the current selected items I **added** a new props **highLightBackgroundColor** in the **ScrollPicker Class** in the index file of react-native-picker-scrollview :

```js
render(){
    ...
    let highLightBackgroundColor = this.props.highLightBackgroundColor || '#FFFFFF';
    ...

    let highlightStyle = {
        ...
        backgroundColor: highLightBackgroundColor,
    };
    ...
```

How to use it :

```js
<ScrollPicker
  ref={sp => {
    this.sp = sp;
  }}
  dataSource={['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']}
  selectedIndex={0}
  itemHeight={50}
  wrapperHeight={250}
  highLightBackgroundColor={'lightgreen'}
  renderItem={(data, index, isSelected) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }}
  onValueChange={(data, selectedIndex) => {
    //
  }}
/>
```

How it looks without others customizations:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same setup with the very popular [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel) package, using the [vertical prop](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel/blob/master/doc/PROPS_METHODS_AND_GETTERS.md#behavior). No need to use a smaller, poorly documented/unmaintained package for this.